# The modf function in C

Tags: c

I have been doing some research on the [`modf()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.12.6.12) function and I am having some trouble understanding on how to use it.

### Code Example

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main ()
{
   double x, fractpart, intpart;

   x = 8.123456;
   fractpart = modf(x, &intpart);

   printf("Integral part = %lf\n", intpart);
   printf("Fraction Part = %lf \n", fractpart);

   return(0);
}
```

**Confusion:** The part I am getting confused on is the `fractpart`. I am having trouble understanding how it actually works because I only want to store the whole number part of a decimal number. Also, what is the point of the `double`.

Comment: "only want to store the whole number". There is nothing that prevents you from ignoring or even not storing the return value of `modf`.

Comment: I want to completely remove the decimal part of the number. @kaylum

Comment: Not sure what you mean. That's what is stored in `intpart`. So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: The `double` is the data type of `x` ,`fractpart`, and `intpart`. [Look here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types) for a listing of C data types. Best of luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of, `double` is something really easy to understand. `Float` only stores seven digits, while a `double` stores between 15-16 digits. More detail [here](https://www.thoughtco.com/definition-of-double-958065)

Now for the `modf`. The `modf` in the `fractpart =`, it first checks `x`. Pretty much scanning it. After it does that, it stores everything before in the decimal point in `inpart`. After, what is remained is stored in `fractpart` which the decimal. To sum everything `modf` is like `scanf`. That is the reason why we put `&` before the `intpart`.

Answer (score 1):

> I only want to store the whole number part of a decimal number.

```
double modf(double value, double *iptr);
```

> The `modf` functions break the argument value into integral and fractional parts, each of which has the same type and sign as the argument. They store the integral part in the object pointed to by `iptr`. C11dr §7.12.6.12  1

Simplified code follows.  No need for `fractpart` or even `intpart`.  Simply store the whole number portion of `x` back into `x`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main () {
   double x = 8.123456;
   modf(x, &x);
   printf("Integral part = %f\n", x);
}
```

Comment: you didn't declare `fractpart` before assigning to it, and you didn't declare `intpart` before print it...

Comment: @ocket8888 Coding mistake amended.